# audio editing web app

Tags: java, audio

I want to develop, as a part of my project, a web application that will enable users to edit, mix and apply effects to audio. I am aware of the J2EE development pattern, but am not sure where to start from. I want Audacity like functionality (actually, sox). Is there any Java API for audio editing/mixing and applying effects? If yes, can one write new effects? This would allow me to dynamically generate effects chains, based on the users' input. I searched the web, but it's all "learn to use audacity..." there. Also, is there any way such effects can be applied in (near) real time?

I found [Soundation](http://www.soundation.com) and [Myna](http://www.aviary.com/online/audio-editor) to be good apps that already do what I want( though Myna has no real time effects support), but they've both got the same old audio editing UI.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at this:

"Movie Masher going open source after Adobe supported it thus allowing integration to your site too." Maybe your solution is here : http://www.moviemasher.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should check these options below:

Web Audio API
http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/

And also
WebPD:
https://github.com/sebpiq/WebPd